# is there a way to make this code shorter / excel worksheet change

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1").Address Then
       Worksheets("sheet2").Range("a1") = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("a1") + Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1")
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1").ClearContents
    End If
    If Target.Address = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a2").Address Then
       Worksheets("sheet2").Range("a2") = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("a2") + Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a2")
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a2").ClearContents
    End If
    If Target.Address = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("b1").Address Then
       Worksheets("sheet2").Range("b1") = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("b1") + Worksheets("sheet1").Range("b1")
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("b1").ClearContents
    End If
    If Target.Address = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("b2").Address Then
       Worksheets("sheet2").Range("b2") = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("b2") + Worksheets("sheet1").Range("b2")
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("b2").ClearContents
    End If
    If Target.Address = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("c1").Address Then
       Worksheets("sheet2").Range("c1") = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("c1") + Worksheets("sheet1").Range("c1")
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("c1").ClearContents
    End If
    If Target.Address = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("c2").Address Then
       Worksheets("sheet2").Range("c2") = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("c2") + Worksheets("sheet1").Range("c2")
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("c2").ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: this question is going to get some negative feedback as posed. You should make some effort to pose the question in as-general a way as possible so that it could possibly be of value to others.

Comment: Is this handler on sheet1 or sheet2? Or neither?

Answer (score 1):

simplify the code by utilizing the cell references built into vba.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim a As Variant
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        a = Target.Address
        Select Case a
                Case "$A$1", "$A$2", "$B$1", "$B$2", "$C$1", "$C$2"
                        With Worksheets("sheet2")
                                .Range(a) = .Range(a) + Worksheets("sheet1").Range(a)
                        End With
                        Worksheets("sheet1").Range(a).Clear
                Case Else
        End Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Worksheet Change on Multiple Cells

- It is assumed that the following code is located in the (sheet) module of worksheet `Sheet1` (`Me`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' c - Criteria - tested
' s - Source - read from
' d - Destination - written to

    ' Restrict to run only if a change happens in the criteria range.
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = Range("A1:C2")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(crg, Target)
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' Note that 'Me.Parent = ThisWorkbook'.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Me.Parent.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    ' Don't allow triggering another event while this one is running.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ' Don't allow to exit the procedure without enabling events.
    ' Study the flow of the error-handling routine.
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim sValue As Variant
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim dValue As Variant

    ' Cover multiple cell changes.
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        sValue = sCell.Value
        If IsNumeric(sValue) Then
            Set dCell = dws.Range(sCell.Address)
            dValue = dCell.Value
            If IsNumeric(dValue) Then
                dCell.Value = dValue + sValue
            'Else 'dValue not numeric
            End If
        'Else ' sValue not numeric
        End If
    Next sCell
    srg.ClearContents ' clear the contents of the cell(s) in one go

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```